# How to fix error in code to make encryption of a text file?

Tags: c, arrays, encryption, fgetc

I am writing a program the will write an encrypted version of a text file(input.txt) to an output file(out.txt). The encryption uses the bit wise XOR operation on the input file and a file containing(keys.txt) two keys with a new line character in between those keys. Everything seems to work right except towards the end of my encrypted output I get a series of unreadable characters.

Input.txt:

"Will you walk a little faster?" said a whiting to a snail,
  "There's a porpoise close behind us, and he's treading on my
        tail.
  See how eagerly the lobsters and the turtles all advance!
  They are waiting on the shingle-will you come and join the
        dance?

Keys.txt:

!

M

The code below contains two print statements to test if the code is even getting the text file correctly. I've noticed that the keys are getting grabbed fine however, the input.txt(str) is not grabbing the entire message. Can someone help me? What is the reason for this??

*NOTE*

My wrong output looks like this:

ov$M!4N8:@!Jm@mM$U9M(+@>U(SrmR,H),:I$U$O*9Nm@mR#@$Ma+mou%D?DjRm@mQ"S=N$R(.M"R(/D%H#EmT>
m@#EmI(>9S(@)H#FmN# Xm+mmmmU,H!Gmr(DmI"VmD,F(S!XmU%DmM"C>U(S>,O)9I(9T?U!D>,M!,E;@#B(

The correct output should be:

m@#EmI(>9S(@)H#FmN# XGmmmmU,H!Gmr(DmI"VmD,F(S!XmU%DmM"C>U(S>,O)9I(9T?U!D>,M!,E;@#B(Gmu%D4,S(:@$U$O*"OmU%DmR%H#F!D`V$M!4N8.N Dm@#EmK"H#9I(+mmmm)@#B(f

The program to convert to hexadecimal (xxd myProgram.c) is used to clarify.

User should type:

gcc myProgram.c

./a.out e input.txt keys.txt

('e' stands for encrypt)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int args, char *argc[]){
  int i=0;
  int j=0;
  int len=0;
  char str[501];
  char str2[2];
  char c;
  FILE *finp;
  FILE *keyFile;
  FILE *fout;

  if ( strcmp(argc[1], "e") == 0 )
  {
    if ( (finp = fopen(argc[2],"r")) == NULL )
    {
      printf("Could Not Open file %s\n", argc[2]);
      exit(1);
    }

    if ( (keyFile = fopen(argc[3],"r")) == NULL )
    {
      printf("Could Not Open file %s\n", argc[3]);
      exit(1);
    }

    while((c = fgetc(finp))!=EOF)
    {
      str[j++] = c;
    }

    while((c = fgetc(keyFile)) != EOF)
    {
      str2[i++] = c;    
    }

    /*Print Statement to test the keys*/
    //  printf("%c%c", str2[0], str2[2]);
    /*Print Statement to test the input*/
    //  printf("%s\n", str);

    /* *** START CODE THAT USES INPUT.TXT FILE and KEYS.TXT *** */

    len = strlen(str);
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
      str[i]^=str2[2];
      str[++i]^=str2[0];
    }

    fout=fopen("out.txt","w");
    if(fout==NULL)
    {
      printf("ERROR");
      exit(1);
    }

    fprintf(fout, "%s", str);
    fclose(finp);
    return 0;
  } else {
    printf("SORRY!");
  }
}
```

Comment: `char str2[2];` .. `str[i]^=str2[2];` : `str2[2]` is invalid.  you need `char str2[3];` or skip white spaces

Comment: there should be a terminating zero to str. the array may not be initialized

Comment: char str2[3] doesn't seem correct to me since at the top of the code: char str2[2];

Comment: If you accepted your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499480/how-to-encrypt-a-text-file-using-bit-wise-xor) why do you ask essentially the same question again?

Comment: Previous question is different from what i'm trying to do here

Comment: `"`^`M` ==> `o`. (not `m`). Perhaps you have misunderstood the correct processing itself.

Comment: Did you come **correct output** is from where? it is correct processing if your program can restore the output of its own.

Comment: yes, it however doesn't return the same text back. Everything except the last line which like you said contains extra white spaces

Comment: 1) it has already been pointed out, C-string requires a termination character(`'\0'`). 2) Conversely, there are cases where the result as the M ^ M (or !^!) becomes zero(`'\0'`). 3) `str[++i]^=str2[0];` : Beyond the length of the string there is a case to the processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *args[]){
    FILE *finp, *keyFile, *fout;
    int i, ch;
    char key[2];

    if(argc == 4 && strcmp(args[1], "e") == 0){
        //Read two key character
        if ((keyFile = fopen(args[3], "r")) == NULL){
            printf("Could Not Open file %s\n", args[3]);
            exit(1);
        }
        if(1!=fscanf(keyFile, " %c", &key[0]) || 1!=fscanf(keyFile, " %c", &key[1])){
            printf("Could Not Read Key properly.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        fclose(keyFile);

        if((finp = fopen(args[2], "rb")) == NULL){
            printf("Could Not Open file %s\n", args[2]);
            exit(1);
        }
        if((fout = fopen("out.dat", "wb")) == NULL){
            printf("Could Not Open file out.dat\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        i = 1;
        while((ch = fgetc(finp))!=EOF){
            fputc(ch ^ key[i], fout);
            i = !i;
        }
        fclose(fout);
        fclose(finp);
    } else {
        printf("SORRY!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```